# kendo toolbar menu button with custom attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Say I've got a Kendo Toolbar, with a Split Button, for example:

```
<div id="toolbar"></div>
<script>
$("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
    items: [
        { type: "splitButton", text: "SplitButton", menuButtons: [{text: "Option 1"}, {text: "Option 2"}] }
    ]
});
```

How could I add the attributes `data-toggle:"modal"` and `data-target="myModal"` to the `Option 1` button?

Is there a 'Kendo' way or do I need to use jQuery/plain JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`items.attributes`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/toolbar#configuration-items.attributes). Your code would be something like:

```
<div id="toolbar"></div>
<script>
$("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
    items: [
        {
            type: "splitButton",
            text: "SplitButton", 
            menuButtons: [
                {
                    text: "Option 1",
                    attributes:{
                        "data-toggle": "modal",
                        "data-target": "myModal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Option 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
</script>
```